# Creating a Stream from High to Low Range

Tags: scala

It's possible to create a Stream by specifying a low and high range:

```
scala> val x = Stream.range(1, 999)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
```

But if I try to make a Stream in reverse order, I get an empty one.

```
scala> val y = Stream.range(999, 1)
y: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream()
```

Also, if I try to simply reverse x, then the whole stream becomes **evaluated**.

```
scala> x.reverse
res16: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 
  993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, ...
```

So, how can I create a Stream with a particular range from `hi to low` without first evaluating it, and then `toStream`'ing it?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Ranges are already kind of lazy (they compute values only on request), and if you're wanting to construct something else from the values, couldn't you just use `tabulate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stream.range` has an overload that takes a step argument:

```
Stream.range(999, 0, -1)
```

This will give you a (lazy) stream starting at 999 reaching down until 1 (inclusive)